# How to dynamically add an item to a list within a list in a ViewModel using Razor and .NET Core 2.2?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've been following this tutorial (i did it in asp.net core 2.2): 
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/ on how to edit a variable lenght list in asp.net. In this tutorial, we're just handling a list of gifts. I'm trying to apply this method to a more complex model.

I have an object called `Workout.cs` who contains a List of `Section.cs`. The `Section.cs` object contains a List of `Movement.cs`

```
public class Workout
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Section> Sections { get; set; } = new List<Section>();
}

public class Section
{
    public int NbRounds { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Movement> Movements { get; set; } = new List<Movement>();
}
public class Movement
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**WorkoutController**

```
        public IActionResult BlankSection()
        {
            return PartialView("_SectionEditor", new Section());
        }

        public IActionResult BlankMovement()
        {
            return PartialView("_MovementEditor", new Movement());
        }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model Workout

<h2>Workout</h2>

<form asp-action="Index" method="post" asp-controller="Workout">
    <div id="editorRows">
        @foreach (var item in Model.Sections)
        {
            <partial name="_SectionEditor" model="item" />
        }
    </div>

    <a id="addItem" asp-action="BlankSection" asp-controller="Workout">Add Section...</a> <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Finished" />
</form>

@section scripts {
    <script>
        $("#addItem").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.href,
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) { $("#editorRows").append(html); }
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>
}
```

**_SectionEditor.cshtml**

```
@model Section
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutEditor.cshtml";
}

<div class="editorRow">
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("sections"))
    {
        <span>Name: </span> @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name);

        <span>Rounds: </span>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.NbRounds, new { size = 4 });
    }

    <a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
    <div id="editorMovement">
        @foreach (var item in Model.Movements)
        {
            <partial name="_MovementEditor" model="item" />
        }
    </div>
    <a id="addMovement" asp-action="BlankMovement" asp-controller="Workout">Add Movement...</a> <br />
</div>


@section Scripts {

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("a.deleteRow").on("click", function () {
                $(this).parents("div.editorRow:first").remove();
                return false;
            });
        });

        $("#addMovement").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.href,
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) { $("#editorMovement").append(html); }
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>
}
```

**MovementEditor.cshtml**

```
@model Movement

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutEditor.cshtml";
}

<div class="editorMovement">
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("movements"))
    {
        <span>Name: </span> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name);
    }
    <a href="#" class="deleteMovement">delete</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("a.deleteMovement").on("click", function () {
                $(this).parents("div.editorMovement:first").remove();
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

With the tutorial, it's working fine when I'm adding sections to my workout, but when I'm trying the same to add movements to my sections, it's not working anymore. I would like to be able to add as many sections as I want to my workout, and for each section, as many movements as I want, and send it to the controller. How could I do that ?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

First: `MovementEditor` appears to be a partial in the controller, but not in the view file (despite the '_').

Second: since `_SectionEditor` is a partial view, you can't define `@section scripts` in it, because it's already defined in the main view `Index`. To solve this issue, you need to put all the scripts in the main view `Index`.

P.S: don't forget to change jquery selectors for items in the partial views, i.e: `$("#addMovement")` will not point to the anchor tag because it was not there when the DOM tree was created. Instead write `$("body #addMovement")` and it will get the anchor tag.

Comment: Thank you. Corrections have been made. But now when i'm trying to add a new movement, i'm redirected to workout/blankMovement